# Javascript MySQL query returns [object Object] in Discord chat, but returns the correct result in the console

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

**My code:**

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
var mysql = require('mysql');

exports.run = (client, message) => {

var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "******",
user: "******",
password: "******",
database: "*******"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT ActivationKey FROM whitelists WHERE DiscordID = '" +       message.author.id + "'", function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err; 
    console.log(rows);
    message.channel.send(rows);
    });
  };
);
};
```

**The Discord Chat Output** https://i.stack.imgur.com/XODNa.jpg 
**The Console Output** https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g1Yo.jpg 
**The MySQL Setup** https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbyK1.jpg

Any help would be greatly appriciated. Please point out even the most obvious, I'm sort of new to Javascript.

I know I'm probably being an idiot, but this issue is really frustrating me and hindering my progress.

Thanks,
Timothy

Comment: don't that smart to include the mysql user/password details in the post.

Comment: So what do you want to show up in the chat, the X-Y-Z thing?

Comment: Please delete your post quickly to remove host/user/password, editing alone let it still be available. Furthermore, change your mysql-password NOW as you have posted it freely to see for everyone on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extract what you need to from `rows` that seems an array of objects:

rows rapresentation:

```
[
  {
     ActivationKey : "WWWW-XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ"
  }
]
```

You can try with this code:

```
message.channel.send(rows[0].ActivationKey);
```

Comment: Thank you worked like a charm. Could you explain why I needed the .ActivationKey?

Comment: `.ActivationKey` is the syntax in javascript to get a property of an object.

Comment: when you perform the query, the method not return only the value of ActivationKey colum to the row you have selected (also if the only field you get in the table).

Comment: The method `query` assumes the returned value can match more then one row and more then one column per row because the method don't know the query you are performing, so it returns an array of object. Sorry but my English is too bad.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `util` package to log the object in depth

```
const util = require('util')

console.log(util.inspect(myObject))
```